# No power to any power outlets in 2007 PT Crusier

Tags: chrysler, fuse

I am been trying to figure this out for the past hour.  I was driving back home from a conference about a month ago and had a power inverter plugged into the outlet inside the center console when all of a sudden it all stopped working.  For the past month I haven't had any power on any outlets and finally today got a chance to change the fuses.

I tried replacing all of the following fuses with none of them working: 11, 12, 13 and 19.

Is there one that I am missing that needs to be changed? I get absolutely no power on any outlets when the car is running or off.  Everything else in the car is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely sounds like a fuse, but you must locate the one that powers accessories. Not sure what the ones you mentioned are, but if it is not for accessories, it is not it.

Comment: That's what I thought. The on'es I changed were for power outlets, ignition outlets (only work when ignition is on) and battery outlets (always powered) and then 19 was what I found online to usually cause the power outlets not getting any power.  No other fuse is labeled power outlet or accessory.